# Hibernate Left join multiple tables with Criteria or HQL

Tags: database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have This:

```
SELECT  * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.IDB = B.ID
LEFT JOIN C ON A.IDC = C.ID

LEFT JOIN D ON C.CODE = D.ID
LEFT JOIN E ON D.IDE = E.ID
WHERE
E.NUMBER = 4
```

A table A that it has association with B and C. Table D has association with E.
Table C doesn't have association with D because c.CODE could contain primary key other table (For example TABLE G).

Is it possible to do with criteria?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Criteria queries can only have one root entity, and navigate through associations. Your joins could be inner joins, BTW.

Comment: Its possible with hql?

Comment: Yes, since your joins are actually inner joins. You'll just need to select from A and D, and to transform your join between C and D into a where clause